# How to remove all and any observer attached to a livedata?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm observing a livedata that is from a room db query. When I change the observer with a different id, I remove the observer that is already listening with previous ID. But when data change occurrs, the observer from previous ID kicks in.

Here's the query for liveData:

```
 @Query("SELECT * FROM table_items WHERE ID=:id ORDER BY ID DESC")
fun getItemsDistinct(id: Long): LiveData<List<Item>>
```

LiveData:

```
private val observer: Observer<List<>> ...

var id = 0

...

viewModel.getItemsDistinct(viewModel.lastID).removeObserver(observer)

...

id = 99 //change
viewModel.lastID = id //update last

viewModel.getItemsDistinct(id)
        .observe(viewLifecycleOwner, observer)
```

Now this approach kicks in last added observer in the list/recyclerView when multiple changes occurs in with a certain ID, instead of the new one added last.

Is there any way to handle this issue or remove all observers before adding a new one?

Comment: [what about MediatorLiveData and having back ref to last query from room? (sorry i'm java dev)](https://pastebin.com/BpyYAnqc) ... and usage: you always observe `ItemsDistinct` and call `setId` to requery with different id

Comment: I this is a LiveData issue? Or is it Room designed that way to notify about the change in the whole table not just a record with requested id?

Comment: Put the last ID in a MutableLiveData, and define your query with Transformations.switchMap

Comment: @Selvin Thank you for the solution, I implemented it and the issue has been resolved. If it was an answer I would mark it as solution.

Comment: EpicPandaForce's solution sounds much clearer - it's doing the same with less code... I completely forgot about transportations..

Comment: @Rifat https://pastebin.com/9bJJmusH using EpicPandaForce's hint ... usage same as my hint - but less code in view model :D

Answer (score 1):

I assume that the `viewModel.getItemsDistinct(viewModel.lastID)` eventually triggers Room and returns `LiveData` directly from it.
In this case, every time you call this function Room creates new `LiveData`. You can check this your self by opening generated code (ex. if you have `ItemsTable.kt` interface, look for `ItemsTable_Impl.java class`). So Room calls an `InvalidationTracker.java` class with `createLiveData` method. That is why, I assume, removing the observer doesn't work.

So, you might wanna use a MediatorLiveData (comment from @Selvin) or, maybe, observe whole table, and later filter only required id, or use something else.

Comment: Thank you for answering and telling me all the info. If I take it as right reason then, If it creates new `liveData`  everytime then can't we track all and destroy them? How many liveData can be created and what if I do not handle any? Will it cause performance issue? 
___  I'll test with `MediatorLiveData`.

Comment: `LiveData` is lifecycle aware object, so you don't have to worry about clearing it, when you're leaving the screen (ex. activity, fragment) it clears subscription automatically. Of course, using it wrong can lead to issues. Without seeing your code I cannot suggest what is (or can be) wrong. Follow google docs and be fine :)

Comment: LiveData is lifecycle aware, its common kinda knowledge. :) . I meant to say manually cleaning or destroying it, just to test or for uncommon situations. 
I followed Selvin's solution, and later I'll test EpicPandaForce's solution. Thanks.